# Escaping ORDER BY clause using mysqli_real_escape_string() function

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using different values in ORDER BY clause of SQL queries based upon user selection. How do I escape this selected value using mysqli_real_escape_string() function?

For example, the url is as following:

```
localhost/person/person_listing.php?sort_by=date_of_birth
```

Based on this I am using:

```
if (isset($_GET['sort_by'])) {
    $sort_by = trim($_GET['sort_by']);
    if (!empty($sort_by)) {
        $order_by_sql = " ORDER BY $sort_by";
    }
}
```

The question is, what is the best way to escape this type of add-on to SQL? Can the entire ORDER BY clause be escaped at once, or each value has to be escaped individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). Your code would look kind of as follows: ([grabbed from here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-examples).

Basically, you add a question mark wherever you have a variable you would want to pass. And then you pass it with the `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` function. `ss` here means that you want to pass 2 strings.

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Name=? ORDER BY ?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $name, $sort_by);
}
```

Comment: The code has to be altered everywhere then. Thanks anyway.